# Swift Boolean Literals (Obj-C @YES @NO equivalent)

Tags: swift

In Objective-C, you can type `@YES` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES]`. This makes for much tidier code.

In Swift, I'm having to write `NSNumber.numberWithBool(true)`, which is kind of ugly.

Is there an equivalent to `@YES` and `@NO` in Swift?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: ...why are you using NSNumbers at all?

Comment: @nneoneo, for Core Data ... i.e. [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:true] which used to be         NSDictionary *options = [
            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

it is `true` and `false`

```
xcrun swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> import Foundation
  2> var t : NSNumber = true
t: __NSCFBoolean = {}
  3> var f : NSObject = false
f: __NSCFBoolean = {}
  4>
```

read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_43

> Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as Int and Float, to NSNumber. This bridging lets you create an NSNumber from one of these types
>
> All of the following types are automatically bridged to NSNumber:
>
> - Int
> - UInt
> - Float
> - Double
> - Bool

Comment: I get "Cannot invoke 'setValue' with an argument list of type '(value: BooleanLiteralConvertible, forKey: NSString!)' (this is Beta7)

Answer (score 12):

> Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as Int
>   and Float, to NSNumber

"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" (iBook).

```
let foo : NSNumber = true
let bar = NSNumber(value: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I you don't have Yes Or no in Swift, Bool true false you have.

If you use Objc-C and call function return Yes or No you may cast this

```
example
// isReady return Yes Or no of Objc-C

if let isReady = object?.isReady {
 //is ready = true or false of your object
}
```